# jQuery selector value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting `undefined` of my variable 'base' which is basic $('slider').value. I have added a console.log(base) to test what is returned, but the value is undefined.

Here is my html:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  let precentage = 17.5;
  let commision = 0.2746;

  function cost() {
    let base = $('#slider').value;
    let precentAmout = base * (precentage / 365 * 30);
    let commisionAmout = base * commision;
    let totalCost = commisionAmout + precentAmout;
    let totalSum = base + commisionAmout + precentAmout;

    console.log(base);


    $('#cost').text(totalCost);
    $('#sum').text(totalSum);
  }


  $('#slider').on('change', function() {
    $('#amout').text(this.value);
    cost();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
  <div class="range-title">
    <h2 class="range-label">Ile chcesz pożyczyć?</h2>

    <div class="display-wrap">
      <span id="amout">500</span><span class="currency"> zł</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="range-wrap">
    <button class="buttons-change-value">-</button>
    <input id="slider" class="range-input" type="range" min="500" max="1500" step="50" value="500">
    <button class="buttons-change-value">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="summary-container">
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>Koszt:<br>
        <span id="cost">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>Do zwrotu:<br>
        <span id="sum">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>RRSO:<br>
        <span id="rrso">200</span><span class="percentage"> %</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do You have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, **.val()** function is available to get value of textbox.

```
 let base = $('#slider').val()
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  let precentage = 17.5;
  let commision = 0.2746;

  function cost() {
    let base = $('#slider').val();
    let precentAmout = base * (precentage / 365 * 30);
    let commisionAmout = base * commision;
    let totalCost = commisionAmout + precentAmout;
    let totalSum = base + commisionAmout + precentAmout;

    console.log(base);


    $('#cost').text(totalCost);
    $('#sum').text(totalSum);
  }


  $('#slider').on('change', function() {
    $('#amout').text(this.value);
    cost();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
  <div class="range-title">
    <h2 class="range-label">Ile chcesz pożyczyć?</h2>

    <div class="display-wrap">
      <span id="amout">500</span><span class="currency"> zł</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="range-wrap">
    <button class="buttons-change-value">-</button>
    <input id="slider" class="range-input" type="range" min="500" max="1500" step="50" value="500">
    <button class="buttons-change-value">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="summary-container">
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>Koszt:<br>
        <span id="cost">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>Do zwrotu:<br>
        <span id="sum">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="summary-box">
      <h3>RRSO:<br>
        <span id="rrso">200</span><span class="percentage"> %</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects don't have a `value` property, they have [a `val()` method.](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the base variable value as a parameter to the cost function like this `cost(this.value)`. That would make more sense since you are already fetching the slider value once via onChange no need to do it again inside the cost function.

Please take a look at the working snippet below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

let precentage = 17.5;
let commision = 0.2746;

function cost(sliderValue) {
    let base = sliderValue;
    let precentAmout = base * (precentage / 365 * 30);
    let commisionAmout = base * commision;
    let totalCost = commisionAmout + precentAmout;
    let totalSum = base + commisionAmout + precentAmout;

    console.log(base);


    $('#cost').text(totalCost);
    $('#sum').text(totalSum);
}


$('#slider').on('change', function () {
    $('#amout').text(this.value);
    cost(this.value);
});})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calc">
      <div class="range-title">
          <h2 class="range-label">Ile chcesz pożyczyć?</h2>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

          <div class="display-wrap">
              <span id="amout">500</span><span class="currency"> zł</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="range-wrap">
          <button class="buttons-change-value">-</button>
          <input id="slider" class="range-input" type="range" min="500" max="1500" step="50" value="500">
          <button class="buttons-change-value">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="summary-container">
          <div class="summary-box">
              <h3>Koszt:<br>
                  <span id="cost">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="summary-box">
              <h3>Do zwrotu:<br>
                  <span id="sum">200</span><span class="currency"> zł</span></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="summary-box">
              <h3>RRSO:<br>
                  <span id="rrso">200</span><span class="percentage"> %</span></h3>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```